# SSL_CTX_new goes into a loop and hangs the application

Tags: windows, visual-c++, openssl, client-server

I'm working on a client application that uses openssl 1.0.2f for streaming data to the server using c++, Where the call to the SSL_CTX_new hangs 60% of the time soon after the connection start. Some times the call returns after a while (recovering from hang after about 30 seconds to 1 minute) and most of the time it doesn't.

here is my code:

```
SSL_library_init();
SSLeay_add_ssl_algorithms ( ) ;
SSL_load_error_strings ( ) ;

BIO_new_fp ( stderr , BIO_NOCLOSE ) ;

const SSL_METHOD *m_ssl_client_method = TLSv1_2_client_method ( );

if(m_ssl_client_method)
{
    sslContext = SSL_CTX_new ( m_ssl_client_method ) ;
}
```

That looks similar to the SSL initialization steps given in the openSSL [wiki](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Library_Initialization)

After debugging through very sleepy profiler I came to know that the initialization of random numbers causes the hang and it looks like it consumes 100% of the cpu and goes into an infinite loop.

Here is a snapshot captured from the verysleepy tool

[image: very sleepy debugging snapshot]

I'm using VC++ and configured whole program optimization and enabled the use of SSE2 instruction set(disabling these optimizations doesn't seem to give any changes in the results).

I have come across a [thread](http://openssl.6102.n7.nabble.com/occasional-initialization-hang-td22774.html) that talks about a similar problem but that doesn't provide a solution for this, I did not find any other threads that talk about this kind of problems, could some one help me with this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problems seemed to be a possible bug in the openssl version 1.0.2h, upgrading it to latest version (1.1.0e) solved the problem.